# Binding not working using angular on Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using angular to populate a form, which can be edited. But the edits are not being captured by the scope variables.

Here's my code:

HTML code:

```
<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Name</span>
    <span>{{name}}</span>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Locality</span>
    <span>{{locality}}</span>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">City</span>
    <span>{{city}}</span>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Amenities</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Amenities" ng-model="amenities">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Total Rooms</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Total Rooms" ng-model="trooms">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
  <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="hotelUpdate()">
    Save Edits
  </button>
</div>
```

**hotelUpdate() :**

```
$scope.hotelUpdate = function() {

  var hotel1 = {
    objectId: $state.params.hotelId,
    amenities: $scope.amenities,
    free_rooms: $scope.frooms,
    total_rooms: $scope.trooms
  }
  Backendless.Data.of( "Hotels" ).save(hotel1)
    .then(function(savedObject){
      console.log(savedObject);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    })
}
}
```

Is there something wrong with the code? On using binding previously the same way, it has worked fine.

Comment: your code looks ok, problem should be in some other part that you do not show. Please post all info

Comment: Also you posted similar question with no response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980477/binding-to-capture-changes-in-form-values. Please post demo in Codepen, fiddle or other online editor that demonstrates your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the function cal,declare a scope variable `$scope.hotel = {}`,

In HTML code,change  ng-model like ng-model = "hotel.amenities",

In controller,change the code to

```
  var hotel1 = {
objectId: $state.params.hotelId,
amenities: $scope.hotel.amenities,
free_rooms: $scope.hotel.frooms,
total_rooms: $scope.hotel.trooms
```

}